# Different observable order of local variable destruction and its return

Tags: c++, return, destructor

I have a program that behaves differently in GCC and Clang. After simplification the minimal reproducible example is

```
struct A {
    int i;
};

struct Finisher {
    A & a;
    ~Finisher() { a.i = 1; }
};

A f() {
    A a{0};
    Finisher fr{a};
    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << f().i;
}
```

In GCC it prints `0` and in Clang the output is `1`. Online demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oW4K93bM8

From the observed program behavior, it looks like Clang first performs `~Finisher()`, which sets `a.i=1`, and only then `return a`. And GCC seemingly chooses the opposite order of operations: first returns `a.i=0`, and only then executes the destructor of `fr`.

Is there any undefined behavior in the program? And is it possible to modify `Finisher` in a way to always change the value of `a` just before returning it from the function (to return `1`)?

Comment: Looks to me like NRVO in action.  With GCC the `A` that gets returned from `f` is initialized before `fr` is destroyed, so it's `i` is `0`.  Clang appears to be doing NRVO and `a` in the function is the same `A` object used in `std::cout << f().i` and so you see `1` as `fr` is destroyed before `cout` prints.

Comment: Minor clarification to the point that @NathanOliver makes: both behaviors are allowed.

Comment: Interesting.  Moral: don't push your luck when writing a destructor.

Comment: How do you actually do an online demo? I didn't see on option on godbolt that let's me share a link to the code.

Comment: @Eldinur: there's a "Share" menu in the top right corner :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears GCC does not perform [named return value optimization (NRVO)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) for some aggregates.

If you add the option `-fno-elide-constructors` to clang, it will give you the same behavior (no NRVO). You can also return `std::move(a)` to stop NRVO. If you add constructors to `A` (like below), both compilers give the same result: they perform NRVO (unless you stop it). Same thing if you add a large member to `A` (like `int arr[100];`).

```
struct A {
    A(int i) : i(i) {}
    A(A&& o) : i(o.i) { std::cout << "A(A&&)\n"; }

    int i;
};
```

NRVO is a form of copy elision, which is one of the only two optimizations allowed to have observable side effects (like make a program print something different). So the program is not ill-formed (no undefined behavior), but it exhibits unspecified behavior.

I am not aware of any way to modify only `Finisher` to make both compilers do the same thing. An easy fix is to put `fr` in an inner scope, but I assume you want `Finisher` to work like a scope guard, which should work in the function's main scope... I believe this issue is one of the reason why [scope_exit](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/scope_exit) is not yet in the standard library. As you can read in the "Notes" of this page:

> If the EF stored in a scope_exit object refers to a local variable of the function where it is defined, e.g., as a lambda capturing the variable by reference, and that variable is used as a return operand in that function, that variable might have already been returned when the scope_exit's destructor executes, calling the exit function. This can lead to surprising behavior.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the other allowed behaviour-changing optimization?

Comment: @Quentin [allocation elision and extension](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new#Allocation)

Comment: That is quite amazingly obscure :D

Comment: Indeed. I actually didn't know about it prior to writing this answer, I just read part of the [cppreference page on copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (the "Notes" at the bottom). :)